# jQuery.siblings not finding siblings

Tags: jquery, asp.net, dom

I have a very peculiar issue with a web system that I'm maintaining. In a view I want to fetch a question number from a label field in my DOM. However my code isn't able to find the label element.

This is the script part.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
                $(function () {
                var result = $(".answer").click(function () {
                    $(this).editable({
                        className: "",
                        saveUrl: "../api/Results/SaveResults",
                        create: function () {
                            var number = $(this).siblings(".number").text();
                            console.log(number);
                            $(this).editable("option", "questionNumber", number);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        });
```

And this is the HTML

```
<div class="questionDiv">
                    <asp:Label ID="questionNumber1" runat="server" CssClass="number"></asp:Label>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="answer1" Wrap="True" runat="server" CssClass="answer" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%"
                            Rows="5" MaxLength="2000" Columns="65"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
```

And rendered in the browser:

```
<span id="questionNumber1" class="number">1</span>
<textarea name="answer1" rows="5" cols="65" id="answer1" class="answer" style="width: 540px; "></textarea>
```

For some reason, number in the create function becomes an empty string. One of the reasons for using `$(this)` is because there are more than one question per page. The `label.text` is set from the code behind in the `Page_Load()` method.

I've been trying with a number of different combinations;

```
$(this).prev().text()

$(this).parent().children(".number").text()

$(this).parent().children().find(".number").text()
```

etc.

If I try these combinations in the chrome console, ie. `$("#answer1").siblings().text()` it works perfectly.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening? All the elements should be rendered as it's done in the `document.ready()` function.

Thanks in advance.

Peter

EDIT: After som more investigation I've noticed that even if I use `var number = $("questionNumber1").text();` I just get an empty string. Could the problem have something to do with the DOM not being loaded fully. The script block is in an `document.ready()` so one would guess that the DOM is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `this` inside `create` method refers to anything else than `$(".answer")`?

Try to backup, possibly it helps:

```
var result = $(".answer").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.editable({
        className: "",
        saveUrl: "../api/Results/SaveResults",
        create: function() {
            var number = $this.siblings(".number").text();
            console.log(number);
            $this.editable("option", "questionNumber", number);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the create: function was wrapping $(this) in another div. So, parent().parent().first(".number") solved it.